# Data Merge fouling up Single Quotes

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

While using InDesign's Data Merge feature, I've noticed that all my single-quotes are getting turned into other non-English characters.

**For example, here's a snippet of the source .csv file:**

[image]

**And here it is merged into a document:**
[image]

Know what's going on here, or a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Your text file is probably non UTF-8 encoded. Re-save your source file in UTF-8 and it should be fine.

Comment: This is not quite correct. InDesign does not handle UTF-8–encoded data sources (at least not CSV sources). What InDesign calls “Unicode” must be UTF-**16**.